# VSCode/Go telling me to go get a package belonging to a subfolder

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-modules

Go/VSCode keeps telling me to go get a package from github, when it is a subfolder which I own.

[image: See linked image]

I have already replaced the route in my go.mod to be a private folder path:

```
replace (
    github.com/brianmaksy/m-highscore v0.0.0 => ./
)
```

The error message that keeps popping up is:

```
cli\server\main.go:7:2: no required module provides package github.com/brianmaksy/m-highscore/internal; to add it:
        go get github.com/brianmaksy/m-highscore/internal
```

If anyone has an idea of what might be wrong, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The problem appears to be that "internal" was an empty folder". As soon as I changed the import to:

```
internal "github.com/brianmaksy/m-highscore/internal/server"
```

the problem was gone.

Keeping this question here in case it helps anyone in the future.